# encrypt aes-256-ctr on Python and decrypt on PHP

Tags: python, php, encryption, cryptography, aes

I try to encrypt data, for example, "qwerty" on Python

```
       encryption_key =  Random.new().read(32) 

       bs = AES.block_size
       iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
       # Convert the IV to a Python integer.
       iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16) 
       
       countf = Counter.new(AES.block_size*8, initial_value=iv_int) 

       cipher = AES.new(encryption_key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=countf)

       encrypted = cipher.encrypt(data)

       return b64encode(iv), b64encode(encryption_key), b64encode(encrypted)
```

and try to decrypt on PHP:

```
$result = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($data['text']), "aes-256-ctr", base64_decode($data['key']), 0, base64_decode($data['iv']));
```

and it didn't work... in $result empty string.
encryption is clearly not my talent :(

I need to make changes in python so that php can decode in this way.

Comment: search hex2bin in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php

Comment: Because of the 16 bytes key `aes-128-ctr` must be applied on the PHP side. Furthermore the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` flag must be set because of the _explicit_ Base64 decoding of the ciphertext. With these two changes the decryption with PHP works.

Comment: I need it the other way around. I need to make changes in python so that php can decode in this way.